# How to monitor which processes access a particular file in Unix?

Tags: c++, c, perl, unix, shell

I have a file and a lot of process (and process threads) are accessing it.

I want to monitor the file to get a listing of what all processes tried to access the file. Being able to record the timestamps also would be excellent for logging purposes, though I can do without it.

- Is there any Unix utility that does something similar?
- In case no such utility exists, how should I program this using a script (shell, Perl) or a program (C, C++)?

Comment: There probably is no generic Unix way of doing this.  For instance Linux has inotify (see Carlos's answer) but inotify only exists in Linux.  Other varieties of Unix have different methods.

Answer (score 9):

Under Linux, [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I second this! inotify also allows you to add hooks that run at certain times: when a file is accessed, written to, appended to, etc; I used it some time ago to automatically git commit files modified in a directory when they changed or were removed

Answer (score 6):

I think the basic functionality you're looking for is in the UNIX command [`fuser`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_%28Unix%29).

This will tell you what processes are using a file (or port if you like).

Comment: Although admittedly it does not make a time-based report - but should be easy enough to build on this to create what you need

Answer (score 2):

FAM - File Alteration Monitor http://oss.sgi.com/projects/fam/
or 
Gamin http://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/

might help you (gamin seems maintained while I cannot say the same for FAM).

You can attach your app to FAM/Gamin and then you'll be notified if something happened with the watched files. 
For details I suggest: http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0650&db=bks&fname=/SGI_Developer/books/IIDsktp_IG/sgi_html/ch08.html

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [`lsof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof).

Comment: A program might have opened it and closed it when I run `lsof`. In this case, it would not be registered with `lsof`. I need a way to continuously monitor the file so that whenever it is accessed by some process, a trigger logs the access to a logfile.